# How to add DOM Element in for loop

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I create new Element each time when (i) will be incremented:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Element child = doc.createElement("xxx");
    root.setAttribute("x", i * "xx");
    doc.appendChild(child);
}
```

Comment: What does the code do instead of what you want it to do?

Comment: Can you show us a bit more of the function this is in? Also, can you write out what the resulting DOM structure should look like versus what it currently looks like? Also, I'm a bit confused about the programming language. Is this Java or Javascript?

Comment: <Server Command="Coupon">
<Print Data=" COUPON TEXT LINE "/>
<Print Data=" COUPON TEXT LINE "/>
<Print Data=" COUPON TEXT LINE "/>
<Print Data=" COUPON TEXT LINE "/>
<Print Data=" COUPON TEXT LINE "/>
<Print Data=" COUPON TEXT LINE "/>
<Print Data=" COUPON TEXT LINE "/>
<Print Data=" COUPON TEXT LINE "/>
<Print Data=" COUPON TEXT LINE "/>
<Print Data="                  "/>
<Print Data=" COUPON TEXT LINE "/>
</Server>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using java

```
    Element child = null;        

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      child = doc.createElement("xxx" + i);//you can write a method with int parameter to get element name from somewhere else 

      doc.appendChild(child);
    }
```

I hope this is what you wanted, by the way for text nodes you should use `doc.createTextNode("A")`

Answer (score 3):

Using pure js

```
var div = document.getElementById("main");

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.setAttribute("class", "new");
  span.innerHTML = "span" + i;
  div.appendChild(span);
}​
```

HTML

```
​<div id="main"></div>​​​​​​​
```

Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/eNBpB/).

Cheers!!